# How to edit particular row inline edit using Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am using Angular8 and initially, it must be bound in a table all values and when click on edit, that particular row should be editable and one row at a time can be edited, I have attached the demo. And here I have added only one array data for demo purposes, but I need to bind multiple years so I tried with reactive forms to add input field and td based on click but couldn't bind values. So here in my case, I need to edit one row at a time.

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of yearManagement">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize">{{contact.policyTypeName}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.quotes}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.policyCT}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.writtenPremium }}</td>
        <td class="width125">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1" title="Edit">Edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1" title="Delete"
                      (click)="deleteCommitment(contact)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxwwwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-maud8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
I have updated the code. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for response, ya to some extent this is solving my problem, i may need your help even more

Comment: Ok I am posting this as an answer please accept and upvote.

Comment: ya please post i will vote

Comment: @AmmarHussain if i click on close i have to revert values newly entered, but currently it is taking same updated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following changes in html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of yearManagement">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize">
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow !== contact.id; else newDeb">
            {{contact.policyTypeName}}
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #newDeb>
            <input [(ngModel)]="contact.policyTypeName" />
          </ng-template>
        </td>
        <td>{{contact.quotes}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.policyCT}}</td>
        <td>{{contact.writtenPremium }}</td>
        <td class="width125">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1" title="Edit"
          (click)="editableRow = contact.id">Edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1" title="Delete"
                      (click)="deleteCommitment(contact)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

And in typescript

```
export class AppComponent {
  editableRow = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have added few buttons, when clicked on edit, edit should be hidden and show save and close button, when cliked on close, it must be back to binding from input box, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kg9b2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html via editrow can that be handled?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygcsxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Have a look now.

Comment: how can we check, when clicking on close, does that row has got some edit or not?